# convert scala dataframe to rdd[(Long,Vector)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, tf-idf

I have a dataframe with two columns `id` and a `tfidfvector(org.apache.spark.mllib.linlag.Vector)`.

I want to convert this to a `rdd[(id,Vector)]` and then convert it to a coordinate matrix.

PS: Can't share the data due to constraints.

I tried df.As[(Long,Vector)] didn't work

Comment: You don't have to use the exact data. Please try to produce a [mcve] with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a dataframe to an `RDD[Row]` using

```scala
rdd = df.rdd
```

after which you can restructure the RDD with map, e.g.

```scala
rdd = df.rdd.map(row => (row(1), row(2)))
```

Comment: yeah but that gives rdd[(nothing, nothing)]